# Set key to toggle full screen in MacVim

Tags: macvim, startup

I use Vim from bash and I use MacVim as a UI in macOS.

I max out my desktops, and try to keep "1 app per desktop", so MacVim sits into its own desktop. Except that the app starts in full screen mode, so I can't see it. (I don't like apps going to full screen, because then they take a different desktop than they are assigned to).

If I was in iTerm I'd use `Cmd+Backspace` to toggle full screen.

What mapping might I add to `~/.vimrc`, or `~/.*imrc`, to get MacVim to toggle full screen when I hit `Cmd+Backspace`?

Comment: What's the syntax here to show key icons?

Comment: Are you using the console version: `vim` or the desktop version: `gVim` (or for Neovim the console version: `nvim` or the desktop version: `nvim-qt`)?

Comment: @vivian-de-smedt As stated in the title: I'm using `MacVim`. I'm not using `vim`, nor `gvim`, nor `Neovim`, nor `nvim`, nor `nvim-qt`

Comment: @romaini thanks for the edits

Answer (score 2):

- MacVim is not supposed to start in full screen by default.
- You can uncheck the "Use native full screen mode" option to prevent MacVim to take up its own desktop when going full screen.
- Vim doesn't know about MacVim's "full screen mode" (actually, it always thinks it is in full screen) so you can't add a "full screen" mapping to your `vimrc`. Which is not a problem, since *there already is a shortcut for toggling full screen*: `Ctrl+Cmd+F`.

  If you really want `Cmd+Backspace`, you can do it at the OS level, in the "Keyboard" section of System Preferences.

Comment: Unfortuantely, something else has grabbed `ctrl`+`cmd`+`f`, and if hit them, I'm dragged away to searching in `Finder`.

Comment: I did find a `~/.gvmirc` which I had forgotten, and that did have `set fullscreen` in it. Now removed. So that's the annoyance gone. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my `~/.vimrc` allows toggling `fullscreen` with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd>

```
nnoremap <D-bs>     :set fu!<cr>
```

This maps a key in `normal` mode, with no re-mapping of keys.

It uses `D` to catch <kbd>⌘</kbd> and then `bs`to catch the <kbd>⌫</kbd>, so that's the `<D-bs>` part.

Once it matches both it sends <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>!</kbd><kbd>⏎</kbd>.

`:set ...!` is the normal way to toggle a vim `option`, e.g. the `fu` option controlling `fullscreen`.

After setting that I have used <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd> to successfully turn Full Screen on and off. This also did not interfere with the same keys when using terminal `vim`, which I previously set in [`my ~/.inputrc`](https://github.com/jalanb/bashrc/blob/__main__/etc/inputrc), etc.